# facebook bot is returning the psid instead of profile id

Tags: facebook, botframework

How can I add authorization to the facebook bot so I can grab the user profile id and not the psid ( page scoped id ) ?

Comment: Include code if you want to be helped.

Comment: If you need to link the messenger id (page-scoped) to other login information, you need to use account linking. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking

Answer (score 1):

Facebook intentionally does not share the profile ID with bot developers, only the page scoped ID.